# Laravel localization throws htmlspecialchars() error

Tags: php, laravel, components, laravel-8, laravel-blade

When I try to use the localization and retrieve translation strings, Laravel for some reason throws: [image].

From the controller to the view (products index page), I pass the `$products` variable. On that page, I use the translation string `{{ __('Products') }}` and getting `htmlspecialchars()` error. As I understood it, translation string for some reason thinks that I passing `$products` variable to `{{ __('Products') }}` translation string, because if I change translation string to (for example) `{{ __('Products page') }}`, I not getting this error anymore. Can someone explain, why this error is occurring?

**Controller**

[image]

**Code when an error is occurring**

[image]

**Code when an error no more occurring**

[image]

**UPDATE**

Fixed problem when added en.json file in the lang folder.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\Localization::class,
    ],
```

you add this created middleware to the list and then you go to the web.php routes file and add

```
 Route::get('/locale/{locale}', function ($locale){
\Session::put('locale', $locale);
return redirect()->back();
})->name('traduction');
```

et ensuite vous pouvez récupérer la session de cette facon

```
<a href="{{route('traduction',['locale'=>'en'])}}" class="menu-link d-flex px-5 active"> 
<a href="{{route('traduction',['locale'=>'fr'])}}" class="menu-link d-flex px-5 active">
```

in case you want to display an image according to the session

```
<a href="#" class="menu-link px-5">
                            <span class="menu-title position-relative">Langue {{ Session::get('locale') }}
                             @if (Session::get('locale') == "fr")
                            <span class="fs-8 rounded bg-light px-3 py-2 position-absolute translate-middle-y top-50 end-0">Francais 
                            <img class="w-15px h-15px rounded-1 ms-2" src="assets/media/flags/france.svg" alt="" /></span></span>
                            @else
                            <span class="fs-8 rounded bg-light px-3 py-2 position-absolute translate-middle-y top-50 end-0">English 
                            <img class="w-15px h-15px rounded-1 ms-2" src="assets/media/flags/united-states.svg" alt="" /></span></span>
                            @endif
                        </a>
```

sorry but you have to use both answers as they are complementary

Answer (score 0):

in truth to translate i don't do it that way. in fact i create a midleware and i create a fair route. let's take the case of french and english. let's create a midleware Location

```
php artisan make:middleware Localisation
```

then fill in the middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class Localization
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(\Session::has('locale'))
        {
            \App::setlocale(\Session::get('locale'));
        }
 
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I published the answer without making it explicit, even though it is incomplete